# How to get webhook data into query string to be read by a custom php script?

Tags: php, string, content-management-system, query-string, webhooks

I have a custom script in php that is intended to receive a webhook from a 3rd party CMS (specifically FLG360), search the source for records that match a given field name in the query string (using $_GET), and return/display the results.

When going to the full URL (including the query string) manually, the query string is read by the script and the correct actions are performed.

However, when sending the webhook from the CMS, it does not seem to be able to find or read the query string.

Here's the part of my script that I expected to be reading and actioning the webhook via simple $_GET requests:

```
$IDtoSearch = $_GET['company'];
$status = $_GET['status'];
```

Is pulling data from a webhook via php as simple as performing some $_GET requests? I have confirmation from the CMS support team that the webhook is definitely formatted as a query string.

I have added this to the script, in order to record any existing query string to the server's error log:

```
//capture the webhook and save to error log
$webhookContent = "";
$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
error_log($webhookContent);
```

...which is doing its job. Here's what I find in the logs after firing a webhook from the CMS:

> eventtype=workflow&eventdatetime=2016-07-29+15%3A16%3A06&eventuserid=&eventusername=&id=109355632&subid=&ipaddress=217.33.80.130&received=2016-06-17+15%3A50%3A37&leadgroupid=49625&leadgroupname=zzALEX+TEST+Applicants+collections&leadtype=FIDOR+Applicant&status=Pre+Default+Applicant+%2336731&progress=Accepted&siteid=16515&sitename=FIDOR+Applicant&userid=32197&username=Aimee+Davies&buyerid=&buyername=&buyerreference=&introducerid=46437&introducername=Alex+Test+cases&reference=&source=FIDOR&medium=&term=&cost=0.00&value=0.00&transferdatetime=0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00&transfersuccessful=No&xmldatetime=0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00&xmlfails=0&xmlresult=&xmlreference=&appointmentdatetime=&appointmentnotes=&lastnotedatetime=0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00&lastnote=&taskexists=No&workflowexists=Yes&dropbox=l109355632.d675cdbf4f75f7d9c6ee99a6b7034b7c%40msrvr.net&fullname=Mr.+Alex+Connor&title=Mr.&firstname=Alex&lastname=Connor&company=TFS9876543&jobtitle=&phone1=&phone2=&fax=&email=&address=&address2=&address3=&towncity=&postcode=&dob=&dobday=&dobmonth=&dobyear=&contacttime=&contactphone=Unknown&contactfax=Unknown&contactemail=Unknown&contactmail=Unknown&data1=&data2=&data3=&data4=&data5=&data6=&data7=&data8=&data9=&data10=&data11=&data12=&data13=&data14=&data15=&data16=&data17=&data18=&data19=&data20=&data21=&data22=&data23=&data24=&data25=&data26=&data27=&data28=&data29=&data30=&data31=&data32=&data33=&data34=&data35=&data36=&data37=&data38=&data39=&data40=&data41=&data42=&data43=&data44=&data45=&data46=&data47=&data48=&data49=&data50=&type1=Work+Telephone+Number&type2=TFS+Number&type3=Current+loan+balance&type4=Contracted+Monthly+Payment+Amount&type5=Last+payment+date+received&type6=Last+amount+received&type7=Next+scheduled+payment+date&type8=Current+Arrears+figure+incl+Legals%2FCharges&type9=Current+Payment+method&type10=Guarantor+is+deceased&type11=Guarantor+has+entered+DMP%2FBKO%2FIVA+&type12=Spare&type13=Actual+receipts+to+date&type14=Applicant+flat+number&type15=Applicant+house+name&type16=Applicant+house+number&type17=Guarantor+relationship+to+main+applicant&type18=Guarantor+First+Name&type19=Guarantor+Last+Name&type20=Joint+App+First+Name&type21=Joint+App+Last+Name&type22=Applicant+has+entered+DMP%2FBKO%2FIVA&type23=Current+Vienna+Status&type24=Solicitors&type25=Legal+Status&type26=Number+of+Months+in+Arrears&type27=Promise+To+Pay+DATE+%28dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy%29&type28=Promise+To+Pay+AMOUNT&type29=Loan+Final+payment+date+%28dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy%29&type30=Agreement+signed+date+%28FOR+DEFAULT%29+-+dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy&type31=Default+expiry+date+%28dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy%29&type32=Less+Rebate+of+interest+%28amount+from+settlement+letter%29&type33=Sum+Required+to+repay+loan+%28Amount+from+settlement+letter%29&type34=Default+ISSUED+date+%28dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy%29&type35=Arrangement+Amount&type36=Arrangement+Start+Date+%28dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy%29&type37=Arrangement+Type&type38=Arrangement+Term&type39=Arrangement+Monthly+Shortfall&type40=spare&type41=spare&type42=spare&type43=spare&type44=spare&type45=DMP%2FIVA+offer+of+Repayment&type46=Reasons+for+Arrears&type47=OFS+LETTER+3+DATE+%28dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy%29&type48=IBC+Referance&type49=Restriction+or+Charging+order&type50=IMPORTANT+NOTES

All the information from the CMS record seems to be coming in, just not being read or recognised as a query string by my script.

Here's what I get when manually entering a query string on the URL:

```
, referer: https://www.domain.com/flg/index.php/?company=cream&status=cheese
```

Not sure what the ", referer:" part means, or why this error is being logged with the full URL as opposed to the above.

Hope somebody can help with this, I'm tearing my hair out.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Many thanks.

Comment: Check the request method. Is it GET?

Comment: "referer" is the page that the request is coming from - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: @Aleksej send me a link to buy you a beer - it was as simple as changing GET to POST. Amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Aleksej in the comments for this - it was as simple as changing the GET to POST. Problem solved, the script is now doing its job.

Answer (score 0):

U can use parse_str() on $webhookContent